# MVC3 Resources File into culture specific folder

Tags: .net, internationalization, resources, resx

I'm currently developing an Web App in MVC3 with C#.

Currently I am attempting to get resources file into their specific culture. I've had success when they are in the same folder

```
Localization\

   Accounts\

    - Resources.resx
    - Resources.es-ES.resx
    - Resources.fr-FR.resx

    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(Localization.Accounts.Resources), Name = "LOGIN_PASSWORD_LABEL")]
```

However I am not able to find them specific culture if they are not within the same folder.

```
Localization\

 - Accounts.resx

   es-ES\
    - Accounts.es-ES.resx
   fr-FR\
    - Accounts.fr-FR.resx

  [Display(ResourceType = typeof(Localization.Accounts), Name = "LOGIN_PASSWORD_LABEL")]
```

Below is the web.config settings

```
<globalization enableClientBasedCulture="true" fileEncoding="utf-8" requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" culture="auto:en-AU" uiCulture="auto:en-AU" />
```